# How to set a const char* variable in LLDB

Tags: c, lldb

I am on an IOS project and we use objective-c.

I function passes some data with type const char*. I can view the data in the debugger:

```
expr -- (void)printf("[%s]\n",(const char *)xml)
```

but I would like to change the value of the xml variable on the fly via the debugger. How can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would do for `char*`:

For `const char *xml = "<xml></xml>";` you can assign to xml with

`expr -- xml = "<foo></foo>"`

Of course `xml` (The pointer to your string) is in the functions scope, so you only change where `xml` in the function is pointing to, not the string that `xml` originally points to (which you can't, beacause you have a pointer to `const`)

This does not work if `xml` is declared as `char xml[] = "<xml></xml>";`, because arrays are not assignable in C.

Comment: Note that `p` is an alias for `expr --` so you can also use `p xml = "<foo></foo>"` and get the desired effect.  (this is same command you would use in gdb)